# Problem with google captcha in laravel, problem with guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

Hi so I have finished all the step that I need to have google captcha at my website. The problem is that I get this error

```
Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\Magang\CMS\cmsglc\vendor\anhskohbo\no-captcha\src\NoCaptcha.php on line 50 (View: C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\Magang\CMS\cmsglc\resources\views\certificate\verify_certificate.blade.php)
```

This is my view

```
@extends('layouts.header_and_footer')
@section('title', 'Certificate')
@section('content')



                
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center mt-5">
    <h1>Search your certificate here</h1>
    <h3>Enter your certification code or your name here</h3>
</div>

@if(session()->has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session()->get('message') }}
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
@endif

@if($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    {{ implode(', ', $errors->all(':message')) }}
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
@endif

<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 mt-5 ">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <form action={{url("verify_certificate/search")}} class="site-block-top-search" method="GET" autocomplete="off">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-inline"> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="s_sertif" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('g-recaptcha-response') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Captcha</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">

                    {!! app('captcha')->display() !!}

                    @if ($errors->has('g-recaptcha-response'))

                        <span class="help-block">

                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>

                        </span>

                    @endif

                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>



@endsection

@section('javascript')
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
@endsection
```

My controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\ActivityLog;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input;
use App\CmsItemEventCertif;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class VerifyCertificateController extends Controller
{
    public function display(Request $request)
    {


        // $test=CmsItemEventCertif::find(1);
        // $test2 = $test->UserSertif;
        // dd($test2);
        // $la=env('APP_URL');
        // dd($la);
        $routes =  preg_match('/([a-z]*)@([a-z]*)/i', Route::currentRouteAction(), $matches);
        $routes = $matches[0];
        $action = $matches[2];
    
            DB::beginTransaction();
            try {
    
          ActivityLog::create([
    
                'inserted_date'=>Carbon::now()->TimeZone('asia/jakarta'),
                'username'=>"-",
                'application'=>$routes,
                'creator'=>"System",
                'ip_user' => $request->ip(),
                'action' => $action,
                'description'=>"Display Search Certificate From Frontend",
                'user_agent' => $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
            ]);

    
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json(['error' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
        }
        return view('certificate.verify_certificate');
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        //$search_stf = $request->s_sertif;
        //dd($search_stf);
       // $q = Input::get ( 's_sertif' );

       DB::beginTransaction();
       try {

       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

        's_sertif' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $desc = 'Failed to search, field cant be empty';
        // DB::beginTransaction();
      
        return redirect('/verify_certificate')
            ->withErrors($desc)
            ->withInput();
    }


        // $sertif=CmsItemEventCertif::where('code', 'ilike', '%' . $request->get('s_sertif') . '%')
        // $sertif=CmsItemEventCertif::where('code', 'ilike', '%' . $request->get('s_sertif'))
        $sertif=DB::table('cms_item_event_certificate')
        ->join('bas_user', 'bas_user.id', '=', 'cms_item_event_certificate.user_id')
        ->join('cms_item_event', 'cms_item_event.id', '=', 'cms_item_event_certificate.event_id')
        ->where('cms_item_event_certificate.code', 'ilike', '%' . $request->get('s_sertif'))
        ->orWhere('bas_user.name', 'ilike', $request->get('s_sertif') . '%')
        // ->orWhere('bas_user.name', 'ilike', '%' . $request->get('s_sertif'))
        // ->Where('name', 'ilike', '%' . $request->get('s_sertif'))
        ->select( 'cms_item_event_certificate.created_at as created_now','cms_item_event.name as event_name', 'cms_item_event_certificate.code','bas_user.name','cms_item_event_certificate.title', 'cms_item_event_certificate.event_id', 'cms_item_event.photo')
        ->get();

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        return response()->json(['error' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    }

    if(count($sertif)>0){

        return view('certificate.verify_certificate_result' , ['sertif' => $sertif]);

        }else{
            $descc = 'Failed to search, record not found';
            return redirect('/verify_certificate')
            ->withErrors($descc)
            ->withInput();
        }
        
    }  
    
    
}
```

My route

```
Route::get('/verify_certificate', 'VerifyCertificateController@display');
Route::any('/verify_certificate/search', 'VerifyCertificateController@search');
```

My config.php related to googl captcha

```
<?php

  

      return [
    
         .....
    
         'providers' => [
    
             .....
    
             Anhskohbo\NoCaptcha\NoCaptchaServiceProvider::class
    
         ],
    
         'aliases' => [
    
             .....
    
             'NoCaptcha' => Anhskohbo\NoCaptcha\Facades\NoCaptcha::class,
    
         ]
    
      ]
```

is there something wrong? I have done composer require, copy and paste related aliases and providers, as well as registering my website(btw at url Im inputing localhost since its still running at local) to google recaptcha and entering the site and secret key to .env

Comment: Laravel 8 sollution  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720254/google-recaptcha-with-laravel

Answer (score 1):

you can take help from the below 2 articles to implement google recaptcha without implementing any laravel package:

[here](https://m.dotdev.co/google-recaptcha-integration-with-laravel-ad0f30b52d7d)

and

[here](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-google-recaptcha-v3-to-your-laravel-app)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this one below, btw thanks for your answer, atleast it give me insight about how the google captcha form works

https://laravel-recaptcha-docs.biscolab.com/docs/intro